# Sum the values of a nested for loops

Tags: python

Can someone tell me in detail of how the the following code produce output 40? May need specify the values of j in details.

```
def temp3(): 
    sum = 0 
    for i in range(0,5): 
        for j in range (i,5): 
            sum += j 
    print(sum)
```

Comment: print value of `j` if you are not able to figure out whats being added to `sum`

Comment: Don't call your variable `sum`, which is the name of a built-in function.

Comment: "Can someone tell me in detail of how the the following code produce output 40?" Well, what do you think it should output instead? Why? Did you try to check what happens at each step of the program?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your code, `i` takes values from 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 & `j` takes values as:

```
i Value               j Values
   0             0, 1, 2, 3, 4
   1                1, 2, 3, 4
   2                   2, 3, 4
   3                      3, 4
   4                         4
```

Now, add up all the values that `j` takes and see what the sum is!